# Constructing a linq query with dynamic ListItem columns that are type boolean

Tags: c#, linq, splistitem, splist

"selectedBA" is the variable that contains a value determined @ runtime.  how can i incorporate this into a linq statement that will give me all the items in a SPList where the dynamic column selectedBA is True in the item.  Probably something simple i am over thinking...  the dynamic column is Type Boolean in the SPList

```
DataTable dt = siteTemplateList.GetItems().GetDataTable();
var query = from template in dt.AsEnumerable()
            where template[selectedBA].Equals(true)
            select template;
```

Comment: i disagree with the negative vote.  i searched google & stack overflow extensively before posting.  No where have i found anyone talking about dynamic columns in linq.  it is always about dynamic values for a columns.  As I have been working crazy OT to get a project done it helped getting a second set of eyes to point out a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
DataTable dt = siteTemplateList.GetItems().GetDataTable();
var query = from template in dt.Rows
            where template[selectedBA].Equals(true)
            select template;
```

Comment: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection'.  'Where' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'template'.